Convert a sorted array into a height-balanced binary search tree by picking middle element -- why does it work?
I was doing an exercise to convert a sorted array to a binary search tree where every node in the tree has its children whose heights at most differ by 1.
One simple solution is to pick out the middle element to be the root. Middle as in (0+size) integer divided by 2 and then make the left, right children by a recursive call on the left half, right half of the remaining array respectively.
And one can check that the solution works via some testing. (Example code in C++ attached at the end.)
However, I am having trouble proving why this solution works.
Why?

I tried reasoning inductively: for any node with height K>3, assume all height k<K nodes are 1) height balanced, and 2) if k−2≥0, then the max possible size of k−2 height nodes + 1 is less than the min size of height k nodes
Since max size is strictly increasing on height, (2) means if height difference ≥2 then the size difference is ≥2.
It's easy enough to prove that any node with height K is height balanced with the inductive assumption. But I am having trouble proving part (2) for K.
Below is a size chart and it also has the base case.



height
min size
max size




0
0
0


1
1
1


2
2
3


3
4
7


4
7
15



The min and max sizes have the following recurrence relations:

min size of height K nodes = 1 + min size of height K−1 nodes + the min size of height K−2 nodes = Fib(n)+n *

max size of height K node = max size of K−1 node x 2 + 1 =2^(n-1) − 1


* last equal sign is "probably"
Fib(n)+n seems greater than 2^(n-1), especially with the rounding relation shown on its Wikipedia page. But then I'd be left with proving this rather involved inequality, going through the rounding relation and such.
Is there something simple that I am missing?
Is there an easier way to prove the correctness of the solution altogether?

    struct TreeNode {
        int val;
        TreeNode* left;
        TreeNode* right;
        TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    };
    void deleteTree(TreeNode* root) {
        if (root) {     
            if (root->left) {
                deleteTree(root->left);
            }
            if (root->right) {
                deleteTree(root->right);
            }
            delete root;
        }
    }

// one can print the tree to Graphviz script for example for inspection; my code for that has a lot of other things together so I'll skip that

// technically meant to be a different file below

#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

#define DEBUG

    TreeNode* sortedArrayToBST(std::vector<int>& nums, std::size_t i, std::size_t j) {     
#ifdef DEBUG
        std::cout << "i = " << i << "\tj = " << j << '\n';
#endif // DEBUG
        if (i >= j) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        else {
            std::size_t k{ (i + j) / 2 };
#ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << "\tk = " << k << '\n';
#endif // DEBUG
            TreeNode* node{ new TreeNode(nums[k]) };
            node->left = sortedArrayToBST(nums, i, k);
            node->right = sortedArrayToBST(nums, k+1, j);
            return node;
        }
    }

    TreeNode* sortedArrayToBST(std::vector<int>& nums) {
        return sortedArrayToBST(nums, 0, nums.size());
    }

int main() {
    std::vector<int> q1{ -4, -3, 0, 1, 2 };
    TreeNode* node{ sortedArrayToBST(q1) };
    deleteTree(node);
}


Let's consider the easy case first.
Write the maximum depth of a leaf for a tree from array length n as
max(n), and the minimum as min(n). Let's define the height of the empty tree
as zero, the height of a tree with one element as 1, and so on (this is 1 more
than a conventional definition of tree height, but it makes things cleaner.)
With that out of the way:
Lemma: (∀k∈ℕ)(max(2ᵏ - 1) = min(2ᵏ - 1) = k)
By induction on k:
Base case: k = 0 gives n = 0, which is the empty tree, and max(0) = min(0)
= 0.
Induction: Let k∈ℕ-{0} be given. Consider the array of length n = 2ᵏ - 1. The
algorithm takes one element to be the center node, then recurses on subarrays each of
length (2ᵏ - 2) / 2 = 2ᵏ⁻¹ - 1.  By inductive hypothesis, max(2ᵏ⁻¹ - 1) =
min(2ᵏ⁻¹ - 1) = k - 1. So *max(2ᵏ - 1) = min(2ᵏ - 1) = k).
Now consider the less round case.
Theorem: (∀n∈ℕ)(max(n) = ⌈log₂(n + 1)⌉ and min(n) = ⌊log₂(n + 1)⌋)
Base case: As before.
Induction: Let n∈ℕ-{0} be given. Let k = ⌊log₂(n + 1)⌋.
If k = log₂(n + 1), then n = 2ᵏ - 1, so by the lemma we have max(n) =
min(n) = log₂(n + 1) = ⌈log₂(n + 1)⌉ = ⌊log₂(n + 1)⌋ and we're done.
OTHERWISE, n ≥ 2ᵏ and n ≤ 2ᵏ⁺¹ - 2 (otherwise we could get an
immediate contradiction on the definition of k).
The algorithm operating on an array  of length n will take one element to be
the root and recurse on children of length ⌊(n - 1)/ 2⌋ and ⌈(n - 1)
/ 2⌉, which lengths we'll define as l and r respectively.
Note max and min are nondecreasing so min(l) ≤ min(r) and max(l) ≤
max(r). We need only check min(l) and
max(r).
l = ⌊(n - 1) / 2⌋ ≥ (n - 2) / 2 = n / 2 - 1 so
min(l) ≥ ⌊log₂(n / 2)⌋,
and we know that n ≥ 2ᵏ so we have
min(l) ≥ ⌊log₂(2ᵏ / 2)⌋ = k - 1.
r = ⌈(n - 1) / 2⌉ ≤ n / 2 so
max(r) ≤ ⌊log₂(n / 2 + 1)⌋, and
we have n ≤ 2ᵏ⁺¹ - 2 so  we get
max(r) ≤ ⌊log₂((2ᵏ⁺¹ - 2)/2 + 1)⌋ = ⌊log₂((2ᵏ⁺¹)/2)⌋ = k.
Thus we have min(n) ≥ k and max(n) ≤ k + 1,
and of course we know min(n) <
max(n) since min(n) = max(n) only in the balanced case
we already ruled out above, so min(n) = k and max(n) = k + 1.

Thank you very much for your answer! Reading your answer helped me realize too that I felt bogged down because at times I couldnt rid of the thought that the tree is determined top-down and the subtrees only depend upwards to their parent in a way. But I get it now. Do you have any other tips for understanding the proof intuitively? If you do, please comment. And btw in n ≤ 2ᵏ⁺¹(k + 1) - 2, you mean n ≤ 2ᵏ⁺¹ - 2 right?

Ah, you're right about that typo. Fixed. Thank you.

Intuitively speaking… my argument wasn't intuitively very different from the one you were making. At each step, we cut the array in half and make each child one step shorter than the full tree will be. The weird edge case is when the child array is less than half the length of n. You might think the child could wind up too small. But what saves us is that the n = 2ᵏ - 1 cases are exact, with their minimum and maximum depths equal, and such an n swoops in to fix it in any case where you'd expect us to get unbalanced. Don't know if that makes any sense.
